# TOC - include "Part" only before numbered parts

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, parts

I generate the following TOC with the code below. Is there a way to not include "Part" before the non numbered part entry?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part} :}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Non Numbered part}
\part*{Non Numbered part}

\part{Numbered part}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Numbered part}

\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that redefine `\cftpartpresnum`  locally  to be empty.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part} :}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}

\newcommand{\addparttoc}[1]{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\def\protect\cftpartpresnum{}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}



\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\addparttoc{Non Numbered part}

\part*{Non Numbered part}

\part{Numbered part}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Numbered part}

\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An abbreviated version of your MWE effectively does what you want (after you have corrected any of my typos).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part} :}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Unnumbered}
\part*{Unnumbered}

\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{Part~}}
\part{Numbered Part}

\part{Second numbered part}

\end{document}
```

Using the default ToC entry style does not print PART which you don't want your Unnumbered part. For numbered parts you have to insert the `Part~` change into the ToC file itself.